# How to vertical align lines of facing pages

Tags: vertical-alignment, double-sided

It is a good typographic practice that lines of two facing pages are aligned. Also, the lines at the two sides of a paper should be aligned. How can I achieve this with `LaTeX`? Especially when having floats.

> : Robert Bringhurst, "The elements of typographic style".

Comment: You are referring to a grid layout. For LaTeX there is the [`grid`](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/grid/grid.pdf) package, while for ConTeXt the [grid layout](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Working_on_Grid) is supported out-of-the-box.

Comment: "grid" package works, although it has some (known) limitations, as with figure placing options. I can stand it! Thank you!

edit: Henri Menke's comment answered my question.

Comment: @HenriMenke Want to make that an answer and get it off the unanswered list?  Thanks.